# Filtering with RegEx

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need to use regex on the string below to capture the IDs whose categories are `b`.

`"id":"1","string of variable length","category":"a";"id":"2","string of variable length","category":"b";"id":"3","string of variable length","category":"a";"id":"4","string of variable length","category":"b";"id":"5","string of variable length","category":"a"`

In this case I should be able to capture `2`, `4` and nothing more.
I tried the pattern `"id":"(\d+?)",".*?","category":"b"`, but that fails.

Comment: I think you need a parser for this.  Did you take this string from JSON?

Comment: Why? That looks like it's part of a JSON file, just parse that file with a JSON parser in your favourite language, and then access the values you need directly.

Comment: It's part of a challenge I've spent way too much time trying to overcome. The goal is to use regular expressions only. It is indeed part of a JSON file.

Comment: Which programming language or tool are you using?

Comment: @blhsing I wasn't sure it mattered. I added a *python* tag.

Comment: Will the down voter please comment on how can I improve my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex `(?<="id":")\d+(?="[^;]*"category":"b")` will do:

```
import re
print(re.findall(r'(?<="id":")\d+(?="[^;]*"category":"b")', '"id":"1","string of variable length","category":"a";"id":"2","string of variable length","category":"b";"id":"3","string of variable length","category":"a";"id":"4","string of variable length","category":"b";"id":"5","string of variable length","category":"a"'))
```

This outputs:

```
['2', '4']
```

Comment: It turns out this minimal example I made up doesn't allow me to solve the challenge using your technique, but this gives me hope. I will keep trying. Thanks.

Comment: I ended up solving the problem I wanted to solve and your answer helped. My issue was that I started with a wrong assumption: that look-arounds do not allow for arbitrary length patterns. This isn't always the case, it depends on the look-around, but I didn't know this and your answer was enough to unlock this crucial bit of knowledge. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you know what characters are legal in the string, you can use something like:

```
"[a-zA-Z0-9|\s]*"(?=,"category":"b";)
```

Which will pull out the string immediately preceding `,"category":"b"`; to get the ID, you could use something like:

```
(?<="id":")\d(?=","[a-zA-Z0-9|\s]*","category":"b";)
```

Comment: Aside: In Python, the `"` needs to be escaped.